# java drawing a circle when mouse clicked

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

i am writing a program that when the mouse is clicked, a circle will be drawn. The below code i've wrote so far.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(10, 10, 10, 10);

    public test () {
        setSize(250,150);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TODO code application logic here
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                   test frame = new test();
                   frame.setVisible(true);
              }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    }

    public void drawCircle(int x, int y) {
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        g.drawOval(x, y, x, y);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 2, 2);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        drawCircle(e.getX(), e.getY());
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

The code is a 400X400 jframe, when clicked open display a circle at a half seconds, The problem is that, when i release the mouse, the circle disappear. why?

Comment: how comes this getGraphics mess is spreading around - a teacher gone wild?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your `mouseClick(...)` to:

```
int x, y;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();

    repaint();
}
```

Override `paint(...)`:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    drawCircle(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you call `repaint()`, the component gets painted again *from scratch*. You're circle is wiped away. You will want to override `paintComponent(Graphics)` which is called every time the component is painted.

Comment: You could also save all drawn circles in an array or list and redraw them everytime

Comment: @Traxdata: Yeah, I was thinking about mentioning that, but this question seemed like a homework question, so I left it to him. :)

Comment: trapped again... :D
Anyway overriding paintComponent(Graphics) would be too hard if it's homework

Comment: Note that the OP is painting in a top level container.  `JFrame` and other TLCs have no `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  OTOH it is best **not** to override `paint(Graphics)` in a TLC, but instead use a `JComponent` or `JPanel` - which has the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.